# Fetch all entries exept those with empty column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

How do I fetch all 'link' entries exept those with an 'url' column that is blank? My controller looks like this:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @links = @user.links.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @links }

    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit #1**

If I do:

```
@links = @user.all(:conditions => 'url != NULL')
```

I get a error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show 
undefined method `all' for #<User:0x2254f98>
```

And if I do:

```
@links = @user.links.all(:conditions => 'url != NULL')
```

I still get all the links, even those with empty url fields...

**Edit #2**

If I do

```
@links = User.all(:conditions => 'url != NULL')
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#show
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: url: SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE (url != NULL)
```

And if I do

```
@links = Link.all(:conditions => 'url != NULL')
```

I still get all the links, even those with empty url fields...

I'm wondering if it's a difference between NULL and the field beeing empty?

**Edit #3**

Now my code looks like this:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @links = @user.links.all(:conditions => "url <> ''")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @links }

    end
  end
```

**Solution**

```
#controller
@links = @user.links.not_null_url

#model
named_scope :not_null_url, :conditions => "url <> ''"
```

This works! Just be sure access the links with:

```
#view
<% @links.each do |link| %>
```

And not:

```
#view
<% @user.links.each do |link| %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its not `@user`, its

```
User.all(:conditions => 'url != NULL')
```

**EDIT:**

Actually i have a doubt. Is `"links"` a column ins users table or is it a model?

**EDIT #2**

Thy this: `@user.links.all(:conditions => {:url => !nil})`

**EDIT #3**

Found it! `url IS NOT NULL` or `URL != NULL` or anything using `NULL` won't solve your problem because, as you said, there's a difference between a null and an empty field. The code below worked for me:

```
@user.links.all(:conditions => "url <> ''")
```

And as @klew suggested, it would be nicer if you use a `named_scope`:

```
#model
named_scope :not_null_url, :conditions => "url <> ''"

#controller
@user.links.not_null_url
```

Comment: Links is a model that belongs_to the user

Comment: ok, i edited my answer based on yours: try `@user.links.all(:conditions => {:url => !nil})`. hope it works.

Comment: Still not working :/ Has it something to do with that it's many links and it's always someone of them that got the url field?

Comment: can't believe! it was supposed to work... could you please post how is your code now? :]

Comment: All links... Very strange... But could it have something to do with that it's many links and it's always someone of them that got the url field?

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand what you mean... but there's no problem having links with and without url. i tested the code i post in my third edit and it worked for me...

Comment: I'm so stupid, I accessed the links with @user.links.each in the view and not @links.each so no matter what condition I used it didn't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@links = @user.links.all(:conditions => "url IS NOT NULL")
```

It would be nicer if you will add it as `named_scope` in Link model:

```
named_scope :not_null_url, :conditions => "url IS NOT NULL"
```

And then in controller:

```
@links = @user.links.not_null_url
```

Answer (score 0):

General Advice: **If your ORM is forcing you to jump through confusing hoops just to execute a simple WHERE clause in SQL, try just using SQL instead.**

Somewhere in Rails, there's a simple way to hand it  ("select * from users where username like '@username' and url not null", username) as a parameterized query and have it hand you a recordset.

It's trivial in the real world, but your framework is making it hard.  Step outside for a second...

Answer (score 0):

`@user.all(:conditions => 'url != NULL')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in Rails3 Table.where(:col1 => !nil, :col1 => !nil)